# Meaning of "acute LSD"

Tags: pharmacology, mrna, psychoneuropharmacology

I am currently reading this research paper: https://www.nature.com/articles/1395848, and I'm confused by this line: "Serotonin Receptor mRNA Levels Are Unchanged by Acute LSD".

What is the exact meaning of this sentence? I could probably understand it as "immediate", that it doesn't pertain to long-term effect instead of short-term.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the abstract they refer to "acute LSD *administration*" (emphasis mine), and in the next section of the results after the one you mention in your question, they clarify it as "Acute LSD administration (1.0 mg/kg, 90 min)".

(That seems like an awful lot to me, as I understand typical recreational doses for humans are in the tens to hundreds of micrograms range.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just realized it now. 1.0 mg by *itself* is a lot, not even talking about 1.0 mg/kg.

Comment: @TimotejLeginus Though these are rats so 1 mg/kg is probably about a 0.2-0.3 mg dose (the paper probably gives specific mass ranges for their animals but I'm just going by my memory of common sizes). Still a lot.

Comment: @TimotejLeginus Just a small addition: the term *acute* generally means that a phenomenon/effect lasts for a short time period, in contrast to *chronic* which refers to a phenomenon that continues over a long period. This doesn't mean long term responses. There can be long term effects of an acute phenomenon.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! well I wasn't so sure about that, haven't found it anywhere, so I had to ask :)